# How to generate all the subsets of a counter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-itertools

I'm required to write a function named `char_counts_subsets` which takes a dictionary of character counts as parameter an returns all the *subsets* of this dictionary considering the values of character counts. An example code looks like this:

```
char_counts = {"a": 1, "b": 2}

def char_counts_subsets(cc):
    return [{},
            {"b": 1}, {"b": 2}, {"a": 1},
            {"a": 1, "b": 1}, {"a": 1, "b": 2}
            ] # ordering of the subsets isn't important

print(char_counts_subsets(char_counts))
```

How can I generalize this function so that it will work with any `cc` dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a combinatorial problem that is best solved using `itertools`.

```
from itertools import product
```

Expand each dictionary item into a range of items:

```
range_items = [[(x, z) for z in range(y + 1)] for x,y in char_counts.items()]
#[[('a', 0), ('a', 1)], [('b', 0), ('b', 1), ('b', 2)]]
```

Take a Cartesian product of each item from the each range with each item from all other ranges:

```
products = product(*range_items)
#[(('a', 0), ('b', 0)), (('a', 0), ('b', 1)),...(('a', 1), ('b', 2))]
```

Eliminate the pairs that have 0 counters, and convert the leftovers into dictionaries with dict comprehensions:

```
[{k: v for k, v in pairs if v > 0} for pairs in products]
#[{}, {'b': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'a': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
```

Answer (score 3):

I like [DYZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62887478/4518341), but I was wondering if it's possible to make it an efficient iterator. DYZ's `range_items` has a space complexity something like O(n+m), where *n* is the number of elements and *m* is the sum of their counts. My solution uses `product` on the `range`s themselves, which I'm pretty sure is O(n).

Also, for terminology, `char_counts` is basically a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)#Multiset), and the output is very similar to a [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), so I guess you'd call it a "power multiset". BTW, check out [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is a multiset object in the standard library.

```
import itertools

def power_multiset(multiset):
    """
    Generate all sub-multisets of a given multiset, like a powerset.

    Output is an iterator of dicts.
    """
    elems = []
    ranges = []
    for elem, count in sorted(multiset.items()):
        elems.append(elem)
        ranges.append(range(count+1))

    for sub_counts in itertools.product(*ranges):
        # "if c" filters out items with a 0 count
        yield {e: c for e, c in zip(elems, sub_counts) if c}
```

```
>>> char_counts = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
>>> list(power_multiset(char_counts))
[{}, {'b': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'a': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
```

Comment: On the other hand, if the size of `range_items` is actually a problem, then the size of the *output* makes this whole task utterly hopeless anyway. Also, the space consumption of `range_items` is only proportional to the sum of the counts, not the product.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the feedback. I edited to clarify. I'm imagining iterating through the sub-multisets one by one, in which case an iterator is more efficient. I also fixed the big-O; is it right now?

Answer (score -2):

without itertools, this works for me. May need a little shortening like a better way to get keys. This is the quickest way for me to do it without looking anything up.

```
def char_counts_subsets(cc):
    subset = []
    for key in cc:
        subset.append({key: cc[key]})
        if cc[key]!= 1:
            for i in range(1, cc[key]):
                subset.append({key: i})
    subset2 = []
    for i, item in enumerate(subset):
        for key in item:
            newitem = {key: item[key]}
            for item2 in subset:
                for key2 in item2:
                    if key != key2:
                        newitem.update({key2: item2[key2]})
                        if newitem not in subset2:
                            subset2.append(newitem)             
    subset.extend(subset2)
    return subset
```

Comment: I suspect that your solution depends on the input: Since my example dictionary has length 2, you are able to solve the problem using 4  nested loops. `for item in subset: for key in item: for item2 in subset: for key2 in item2:` But it wouldn't work as you expected if you add another key to the dictionary.

Comment: I ran this and it worked for me:                                                                   
char_counts = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}

Comment: The order is not perfect but it does give all subsets

Comment: here is the result  [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'b': 1}, {'c': 3}, {'c': 1}, {'c': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}, {'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': 2}, {'b': 1, 'a': 1, 'c': 2}, {'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'c': 1, 'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'c': 2, 'a': 1, 'b': 1}]

Comment: These are missing in your result for `{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}`: `[{}, {'b': 1, 'c': 1}, {'b': 1, 'c': 2}, {'b': 1, 'c': 3}, {'b': 2, 'c': 1}, {'b': 2, 'c': 2}, {'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 1, 'c': 1}, {'a': 1, 'c': 2}, {'a': 1, 'c': 3}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]`