# Generating the powerset of a multiset

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, pseudocode, multiset

Suppose I have a multiset

```
{a,a,a,b,c}
```

from which I can make the following selections:

```
{}
{a}
{a,a}
{a,a,a}
{a,a,a,b}
{a,a,a,b,c}
{a,a,a,c}
{a,a,b}
{a,a,b,c}
{a,a,c}
{a,b}
{a,b,c}
{a,c}
{b}
{b,c}
{c}
```

Notice that the number of selections equals 16. The cardinality of a powerset of a multiset, `card(P(M))`, is defined on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/wiki/Multisets) as

```
card(P(M)) = prod(mult(x) + 1) for all x in M
```

where `mult(x)` is the multiplicity of `x` in `M` and `prod` is the product of the terms. So for our example, this would amount to 4 x 2 x 2 = 16.

Let's say, for example, that the multiplicity of these elements is very high:

```
m(a) = 21
m(b) = 36
m(c) = 44
```

Then

```
card(P(M)) = 22 * 37 * 45 = 36630.
```

But if we were to treat all those elements as distinct - as a **set** - the cardinality of the powerset would be

```
card(P(S)) = 2^(21+36+44) = 2535301200456458802993406410752.
```

The "standard" solution for this problem suggests to just compute the powerset of the set where all of the elements are treated as distinct, and then prune the results to remove the duplicates. That's a solution with `O(2^n)` complexity.

Does a general algorithm for generating a powerset of a multiset with complexity on the order of `card(P(M))` exist?

Comment: You could use ```Itertools.combinations```. https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: Wasn't this a [python] question three days ago? Now it's [pseudocode]?

Comment: For each (distinct) element in the multiset, count how many times, n, it is included, then there are n+1 options on how many times to include that element in the multiset. For your example {a, a, a, b, c}, there are 3 a's, so there are 4 options to whether a will be in a subset no times, once, twice, or three times. For b and c, there are only 2 options, respectively include the element, or don't include it. Multiply the possibilities to get 2*2*4 = 16 different subsets in the powerset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `powerset` recipe with `itertools`

What you are asking is usually called the `powerset` and is available as an `itertools` recipe, as well as a function in the module `more_itertools`. See the documentation:

- [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes);
- [`more_itertools.powerset`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.powerset).

```py
multiset = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']

#
# USING ITERTOOLS
#
import itertools

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

print(list(powerset(multiset)))
# [(), ('a',), ('a',), ('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('a', 'a'), ('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c')]

#
# USING MORE_ITERTOOLS
#
import more_itertools

print(list(more_itertools.powerset(multiset)))
# [(), ('a',), ('a',), ('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('a', 'a'), ('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c')]
```

### Powerset of a `collections.Counter` object

In Python, multisets are usually represented with a `collections.Counter` rather than with a `list`. The class `collections.Counter` is a subclass of `dict`; it implements dictionaries that map elements to counts, as well as several useful methods such as building a `Counter` by counting occurrences in a sequence.

Taking the powerset of a `Counter` is the topic of another question on stackoverflow:

- [How to generate all the subsets of a Counter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887283/how-to-generate-all-the-subsets-of-a-counter)

Although I am not aware of an already-implemented method doing this in standard modules, the answer to that question presents one solution using `itertools`:

```py
import collections
import itertools

multiset = collections.Counter(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
# Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 1})

def powerset(multiset):
    range_items = [[(x, z) for z in range(y + 1)] for x,y in multiset.items()]
    products = itertools.product(*range_items)
    return [{k: v for k, v in pairs if v > 0} for pairs in products]

print(powerset(multiset))
# [{}, {'c': 1}, {'b': 1}, {'b': 1, 'c': 1}, {'a': 1}, {'a': 1, 'c': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, {'a': 2}, {'a': 2, 'c': 1}, {'a': 2, 'b': 1}, {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 3, 'c': 1}, {'a': 3, 'b': 1}, {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all the combinations of `lst` as `tuples`. Hope this answers your question.

```
from itertools import combinations
lst = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']

combs = set()

for i in range(len(lst)+1):
    els = [tuple(x) for x in combinations(lst, i)]
    for item in tuple(els):
       combs.add(item)

print(combs)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I like to think of it is that you start out with the empty set and then for each character you are making a choice of either adding it to the current existing sets or not adding it. Since you have 2 choices at each step, the number of total elements in a powerset is 2^n. Implementing this can be done through this Java code:

```
    public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
    
    // list variable contains all of the subsets

    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // add the empty set to start with
    list.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        //find current list size
        int length = list.size();
        
        // Loop through and add the current element to all existing 
        subsets
        //Represents making the choice of adding the element
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            // making a copy of current subset list
            ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>(list.get(j));
            temp.add(nums[i]);
            list.add(temp);
        }
    }
    
    return list;
}
```