# Generating subsets recursively solution in a specific order

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, subset

I came across the following problem and I am unsure of how to solve it:

Print all subsets except the empty set in the order of how numbers appear in the given input set.

```
Sample input:
5 3 8

Sample output:
5
3
8
53
58
38
538
```

My question is, how can I go about this? I know that to generate all subsets I can use the following code (in python):

```
numbers = [5, 3, 8]

n = len(numbers)

ans = [0] * n

def subset(pos):
    if pos == n:
        print(ans)
        return

    ans[pos] = 0
    subset(pos + 1)
    ans[pos] = 1
    subset(pos + 1)

subset(0)
```

Comment: Since you like python, have you tried with the `powerset` recipe from `itertools`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68032938/3080723

Comment: I can post the answer in C++ using BFS. I don't know if it will be helpful for you but you would get the basic idea behind it.

Comment: Thank you,

@Stef I would like to solve this purely recursively as I am hoping to build my understanding. i.e. I would like to implement the logic myself.

risingStark, if you could that would be helpful indeed. I am familiar with BFS just not how to solve this recursively.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following algorithm:

- let size increase from 1 to the size of the input.
- For each size, use recursion to select that many elements from the list.

I suppose you are looking for the algorithm, so although I will use Python here, I'll not use libraries such as itertools.

```py
def subsets(values):
    result = []

    def recur(start, size, selection):
        if not size:
            result.append(selection)
        else:
            for i in range(start, len(values) - size + 1):
                recur(i + 1, size - 1, selection + [values[i]])
    
    for size in range(1, len(values)+1):
        recur(0, size, [])

    return result

# Example run:
result = subsets([3, 8, 5])
print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks @trincot, this is very clear. Looks like I'll need to spend more time on getting to grips with recursion.

Answer (score 1):

A different recursive approach:

To get the powerset of `'abc'`, take the powerset of `'bc'`, then add `'a'` in front of every element, or not.

```py
def powerset(seq):
  if len(seq) == 0:
    return [[]]
  else:
    p = powerset(seq[1:])
    return [[seq[0]]+c for c in p] + p

print(powerset('abc'))
# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['b'], ['c'], []]
# |_____________________________________________|  |___________________________|
#        powerset of 'bc' with 'a' in front               powerset of 'bc'
```

Comment: Thanks @Stef, this is very elegant. I guess I need much more practice before I can climb this recursive wall.

Comment: @finite_diffidence It is often said that functional programming and recursion is actually easier and more natural than imperative programming and iteration. One trick to come up with a recursive function is to imagine that one of your friend has already solved the problem, but his solution has a limitation and will only handle items up to size `n-1`. So all you have to do is write a function that takes items of size `n`, break them down into items of size at most `n-1`, then calls your friend's function, and use the result of that call to figure out the result for your case.

Comment: Here for instance, I used the result of `powerset(seq[1:])` to figure out the result of `powerset(seq)`