# Best way to find divisors of a number

Tags: python, math, optimization, primes, division

I have a function that finds the prime divisors of a number and returns a list of its prime factors:

```
def prime_factors(n, listFact=[]):
    end = floor(sqrt(n))
    if n == 1:
        return listFact
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return prime_factors(n // 2, listFact + [2])
    elif n % 3 == 0:
        return prime_factors(n // 3, listFact + [3])
    for j in range(6, end + 2, 6):
        p1, p2 = j - 1, j + 1
        if n % p1 == 0:
            return prime_factors(n // p1, listFact + [p1])
        elif n % p2 == 0:
            return prime_factors(n // p2, listFact + [p2])
   return listFact + [n]
```

So, prime_factors(120) = [2, 2, 2, 3, 5].

How can I calculate the divisors optimally from this list? My approach was very cumbersome, by adding a function called counts that returns a dictionary of the times each factor appears. So, counts(prime_factors(120)) = {2: 3, 3: 1, 5: 1}. The program is:

```
def find_divisors_v2(n):
    dict_primes = counts(prime_factors(n))
    big_list = []
    for k, v in dict_primes.items():
        big_list.append([(k, i) for i in range(v+1)])
    divisors_perms = list(itertools.product(*big_list))
    divisors = []
    for perm in divisors_perms:
        d = 1
        for i in perm:
            d *= i[0]**i[1]
        divisors.append(d)
    return divisors
```

But surprisingly it is faster than calculating it on the usual manner, i.e.:

```
def find_divisors(n):
    divisors = []
    bound = ceil(sqrt(n)) + 1
    for d in range(1, bound):
        if n // d == d:
            divisors.append(d)
        elif n % d == 0:
            divisors.append(d)
            divisors.append(n//d)
    return divisors
```

Is there a way to extract the divisors from a list of the prime factors that is more computationally efficient? Or maybe do it by modifying the prime_factors function?

Comment: @wim I'm doing a for i in range(2, 100000): find_divisors(j) and the same with find_divisors_v2 and the first one takes 2.1s and the second one takes 1.1s (rough average). If I increase the values, find_divisors_v2 does even better in comparison

Comment: You can just use `collections.Counter()` to get the counts from a list.

Comment: Please search for duplicates before posting. I literally put just `divisors` into the site search and the linked duplicate was the fifth result. In a listing that includes results for every programming language, every technology tag, and mixed questions and answers.

Comment: `if n // d == d: divisors.append(d)` <<< This part is wrong!! Consider for instance n = 18, d = 4. Then `n // d == d` but that has nothing to do with `d` being a divisor of `n`. I think what you wanted instead was `if d * d == n: divisors.append(d)`

Comment: @Stef yep, I realized a few hours later, while testing the function. Thanks for pointing it out, tho!

Comment: Instead of `end = floor(sqrt(n))` I recommend `end = isqrt(n)` (with `from math import isqrt`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one time I had to do this, I essentially wrote the same as find_divisors2, but optimized so that I wasn't calculating the same powers over and over again.

```
def factor_list(value: int) -> Sequence[int]:
    # prime_factor_list is something like ((2, 3),(3, 1)) for 24
    def recurse(prime_factor_list) -> Sequence[int]:
        if not prime_factor_list:
            return [1]
        *start_factor_list, (prime, count) = prime_factor_list
        sub_factors = recurse(start_factor_list)
        powers = [prime ** i for i in range(0, count + 1)]
        return [factor * power for factor in sub_factors for power in powers]

    # prime_factors returns a list of tuple[int, int] giving prime and power
    result = sorted(recurse(prime_factors(value)))
```

Comment: I wished I knew why this got negative points.  It answers the question and is more efficient that the given answer.

Comment: Probably because it's a duplicate and people get mad or something

Comment: @BraisRomero See also this related question: [How to generate all the subsets of a counter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887283/how-to-generate-all-the-subsets-of-a-counter). It suggests you can do `def factor_list(prime_factor_list):  return [math.prod(p**k for (p,k) in comb) for comb in itertools.product(*([(p, k) for k in range(j + 1)] for p,j in prime_factor_list))]`